# How to simulate inheritance in Clojure?

Tags: scala, parsing, inheritance, clojure, polymorphism

I recently started looking into Clojure, so admittedly I do not have much
experience nor have I read every book about it. Still, I am having a hard
time figuring out how to expand the behavior of systems coded in Clojure.

To be more specific, for educational purposes, some time ago I implemented
parsers in Scala for a family of small languages -- the NAND-CIRC language
family, similar to how it is defined in [“Introduction to Theoretical Computer
Science”](https://introtcs.org/public/index.html), by Boaz Barak. There is a
*pure* version of the language, and then there are successive syntax sugars that
can be added (inline functions, user-defined functions, if/else, and for).

In Scala -- using the parser combinators library -- I could define the basic
grammar as a class, as shown below (the semantic actions are omitted for
brevity).

```scala
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class NandCircParsers extends RegexParsers {

  def program: Parser[Any] = block
  
  def block: Parser[Any] = rep(command)
  
  def command: Parser[Any] = opt(statement) ~ rep(eol)
  
  def statement: Parser[Any] = assign
  
  def assign: Parser[Any] = reference ~ "=" ~ funcall
  
  def reference: Parser[Any] = outputPort | variable
  
  def funcall: Parser[Any] = identifier ~ "(" ~ actualArgs ~ ")"
  
  def actualArgs: Parser[Any] = repsep(expression, ",")
  
  def expression: Parser[Any] = inputPort | reference
  
  def variable: Parser[Any] = identifier
  
  def inputPort: Parser[Any] = "X" ~ "[" ~ index ~ "]"

  def outputPort: Parser[Any] = "Y" ~ "[" ~ index ~ "]"

  def identifier: Parser[Any] = """[_a-zA-Z$][_a-zA-Z0-9'$]*""".r
  
  def index: Parser[Any] = number
  
  def number: Parser[Any] = """[-+]?[0-9]+""".r
  
}
```

Then I could create an instance of the class `NandCircParsers` and use it to
process the *vanilla* version of the language.

But one other *dialect* of the language NAND-CIRD allows the use of inline
functions. For that, the production rule for `expression` must change. In Scala
that is a matter of creating a subclass and overriding the method in question.

```scala
class NandCircInlineParsers extends NandCircParsers {
  
  override def expression: Parser[Any] = inputPort | reference | funcall
  
}
```

And then I can instantiate the class `NandCircInlineParsers` and use the new
*dialect* without having to rewrite all the grammar, i.e., the parser hierarchy.

For the dialect with if/else syntax sugar (only) the situation is similar.

```scala
class NandCircIfParsers extends NandCircParsers {
  
  override def statement: Parser[Any] = assign | ifSttmt
  
  def ifSttmt: Parser[Any] = 
    "if" ~ expression ~ ":" ~ block ~ opt("else" ~ ":" ~ block) ~ "end"
    
}
```

I just have to override the production rule of the grammar (method) that changed
and add the new ones and I have a parser for the new dialect.

But this is in Scala. Now I am trying to achieve an equivalent result with Clojure.

I have implemented a parser combinators library that goes in the line of what
was done for the `parsec.el` [Emacs Lisp parser combinator
library](https://github.com/cute-jumper/parsec.el), and for my needs, it is
working.

The parser for the *vanilla* version of the NAND-CIRC language becomes
something like this.

```clj
(def EQU    (token (literal "=")))
(def COMMA  (token (literal ",")))
(def LPAR   (token (literal "(")))
(def RPAR   (token (literal ")")))
(def LBKT   (token (literal "[")))
(def RBKT   (token (literal "]")))
(def IN     (token (literal "X")))
(def OUT    (token (literal "Y")))

(def ident  (token (regex #"[_a-zA-Z$][_a-zA-Z0-9'$]*")))
(def number (token (regex #"[-+]?[0-9]+")))

(def variable ident)

(def index number)

(def input (do* IN LBKT index RBKT))

(def output (do* OUT LBKT index RBKT))

(def expr (choice input output variable))

(def actual-args (sep-by expr COMMA))

(def funcall (do* ident LPAR actual-args RPAR))

(def formal-args (sep-by var COMMA))

(def reference (either output variable))

(def assign (do* reference EQU funcall))

(def command (do* (optional assign) (many eol)))

(def statement command)

(def program (many command))
```

Readability issues aside, my question is: how can I achieve the same level of
code reuse that I have in Scala with Clojure? How can I turn this design modular
enough that I could only change or add the necessary rules to get a new dialect
of the language? Right now, all I can think about -- that does not involve
implementing an object system with inheritance -- is to duplicate the entire
grammar.

Does Clojure have any resources that can facilitate this?

Thanks.

Comment: I used Closure a long time ago but I think `deftype`/`defrecord` and `reify` are what you are looking for, see [the docs](https://clojure.org/reference/datatypes), alternatively it might be [protocols](https://clojure.org/reference/protocols)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very much like something that could be implemented using maps. The basic grammar `NandCircParsers` could be

```clj
(def NandCircParsers
  {:program program
   :block block
   :command command
   :statement statement
   ... ...})
```

From this grammar, we can create an extended grammar `NandCircIfParsers` that uses [`merge`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge) to inherit from `NandCircParsers`. Something like this, maybe:

```clj
(def NandCircIfParsers
  (let [ifSttmt ...]
    (merge NandCircParsers
           {:statement (choice (:assign NandCircParsers) ifSttmt)
            :ifSttmt ifSttmt})))
```